# Micro SDHC card won't mount on Sylvania SYNET7LP-DS

Tags: 2.2-froyo, external-sd, sd-card, mount

My new Class 4 PNY 16GB Micro SDHC card won't mount on my Sylvania SYNET7LP-DS 32GB Extended storage Froyo (2.20) Tablet. This is the second new card I returned, and still won't mount. When I press the `Mount SD` option, it says `Memory Device Safe To Remove`.

I should also note that the `Format SD Card` option is not showing up on the Tablet at all. I mean it's not there in grey or anything.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I have same tablet with same problem , this is not merely a co-incidence .

Comment: As [DanL's answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/43555/16575) already indicates: there are sometimes incompatibility issues. Not every SDCard seems to run fine with every device. Try a different brand (and remember the one you've got now generally might not work with your device).

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same tablet. I just installed a 32Gb micro sdhc and it worked right off the bat. It came pre-formatted, I installed it with power off, and on power up it was recognized and mounted.
Polaroid 32 GB CL10 micro SDHC Flash Memory Cards for Tablet PCs and Smartphones (P-SDU32G10-EFPOL)